# How does disassembler recognize a instruction?

Tags: disassembly

For example in IA-32 instructions.

```
0x00401000 = 0x8B
0x00401001 = 0x75
0x00401002 = 0xF0
0x00401003 = 0x03
0x00401004 = 0xD1
0x00401005 = 0x8D
```

I have those codes in my process and when I readprocessmemory from 0~5,
disassembler knows that 0x8B 0x75 0xF0 is one instruction.

```
8B75 F0 =  MOV ESI,[EBP+0xF0]
```

But, what if I read it from 1~5. I will miss 0x8B from one instruction.
Will disassembler skip it?

Comment: If the disassember starts with `0x75` then it's going to try to interpret it as an instruction code. If it can't, it will show it as a data byte in your code space and move on to the next byte.

Answer (score 0):

If the disassember starts with 0x75 then it's going to try to interpret it as an instruction code. If it can't, it will show it as a data byte in your code space and move on to the next byte. –  lurker